# Jumping to a byte offset, and displaying position as byte offset

Tags: cursor-movement, statusline, binary-file

How can I move the cursor to the *n*<sup>th</sup> byte in the buffer?

How can I display the current cursor position in the ruler in terms of the byte offset, rather than lines and columns?  (Follow-up question: can it be displayed in both decimal and hexadecimal?)

Comment: Note that byte offset n and nth byte aren't the same thing. Byte 1 is at offset 0, byte 78 is at offset 77, etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
:goto 2356
```

jumps to the 2356th byte in the buffer.

Use the `%o` field in `'statusline'` or `'rulerformat'` to display the byte number of the character under your cursor.

Use `%O` to display the value in hexadecimal format.

Reference:

```
:help :goto
:help 'statusline'
:help 'rulerformat'
```

Comment: I found this only worked when opening the file in binary mode: `vi -b <filename>`

Answer (score 11):

You can hit <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> and you get the full information about the position:

```
Col 13 of 35; Line 18 of 2272; Word 70 of 7767; Char 410 of 50021; Byte 410 of 50118
```

Answer (score 3):

To display the byte position you can use the following command

```
:echo line2byte(line("."))+col(".")-1
```

[See Question: Get offset of current buffer in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483796/get-offset-of-current-buffer-in-vim-in-particular-via-python-scripting)

Comment: Probably, Vivian De Smedt forgot one `)` in the end of line.
Let me guess that he meant `:echo(eval(line2byte(line("."))+col(".")-1))`

Comment: I would rather recommend to use `:echo eval(line2byte(line("."))+col(".")-1)` (e.g. remove the very first `parenthesis`)

Comment: @SamCenzored I've converted your answer to a comment, for now, since it seemed like you were clarifying a post (see https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Welcome to [vi.se]!