# Go to X bytes from here

Tags: cursor-movement, binary-file

How can I move X bytes forward, starting from the current cursor location (including line breaks)?

[`[count]go`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#go) could be used to move forward X bytes from the start of the buffer. I tried `Shift + V, G, [count]go` (assuming that `[count]go` would start counting from the begin of my selection), but unfortunately that did not work either because `go` only starts counting from the begin of the buffer.

I have also tried `:set rulerformat=%o` to display the current byte offset (as suggested by [Jumping to a byte offset, and displaying position as byte offset](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/jumping-to-a-byte-offset-and-displaying-position-as-byte-offset)), added the numbers in my head and finally issued `[count]go`. This works, but it is not very practical...

Comment: If everything is on one line, you can use `Xl` (where `X` is the number of characters) or the number of characters followed by Right arrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using the following solution, which implements the logic from my question.

- `[count]GO` to move `[count]` bytes forward.
- `[count]Go` to move `[count]` bytes backwards.

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! JumpToByte(byte_nr)
    " See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3911/2720 for the byte counting bug
    let crt_byte = line2byte(line('.')) + col('.') - 1
    if version < 781 && &l:binary == 1 && &l:eol == 0
        let crt_byte += 1
        let crt_byte += line('.') == 1
    endif
    let dst_byte = crt_byte + a:byte_nr
    execute "normal " . dst_byte . "go"
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <silent> GO ":<c-u>call JumpToByte(" . v:count . ")<cr>"
nnoremap <expr> <silent> Go ":<c-u>call JumpToByte(-" . v:count . ")<cr>"
```

Thanks to VanLaser for his initial implementation, which put me in the right direction.

Comment: One question, where exactly do you need this functionality? (BTW I ended up combining your solution with reusing the previous count if none is provided).

Comment: @VanLaser I was reading the raw contents of a PDF file, in order to get a better understanding of the PDF file format. A PDF file consists of many objects, and many of these objects have a length prefix. Being able to jump X bytes ahead was useful for debugging. And before you ask why I'm editing raw PDF files: I am developing a new feature for [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) which requires a deeper knowledge of the PDF file format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and good luck)! The combined version is here, if interested: http://pastebin.com/7sVyiA85

Comment: @VanLaser I've updated my answer with a final version. It turns out that your original line counting method was fine, but there was a bug in Vim. I've submitted [a patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/zX45zm-cnc0/-BWjjh5tlX8J) which [got accepted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/PnMWN0rujOk/hRxX91VZAc4J), so in the latest version of Vim, your answer will also work as intended.

Comment: You seem to have done some real digging there (going to the source) - congratulations!

Answer (score 12):

This search moves 40 *chars* (not bytes, though) forward:

```
/\_.\{40}/e
```

by searching for exactly 40 chars (`\{40}`) of any kind, including newline (`\_.`), and placing the cursor at the end of the search (`/e`). See: http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy, `:help search-offset` and `:help \_`

Also, see `:h 23.4` for binary editing.

---

Update: Based on [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/how-to-get-the-current-byte-offset-in-whole-file) answer, here's a function that jumps to byte offset:

```
let s:last_jump_bytes = 0

function! JumpTo(byte_nr)
    let crt_byte = line2byte(line('.')) + col('.')
    if (a:byte_nr == 0)
        let dst_byte = crt_byte + s:last_jump_bytes
    else
        let dst_byte = crt_byte + a:byte_nr
        let s:last_jump_bytes = a:byte_nr
    endif
    let dst_line = byte2line(dst_byte)
    let dst_col = dst_byte -line2byte(dst_line)
    "remove next line if you don't want to record this for `Ctrl-O`
    execute "normal " . dst_line . "G"
    call setpos('.', [0, dst_line, dst_col])
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 JumpToOffset :call JumpTo(<f-args>)

" silly mapping to Ctrl-C (demo)
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <c-c> ":<c-u>call JumpTo(" . v:count . ")<cr>"
```

Can be used like this:

```
:JumpToOffset 400
```

or typing the mapped keyboard mapping,  with a count:

```
40CTRL-C
```

If you don't use a count, the previous count number is re-used. So you can do: `40CTRL-C CTRL-C CTRL-C 30CTRL-C CTRL-C` to jump 40, 40, 40, 30, 30 bytes etc.

Hit `Ctrl-O` to jump back (see comments inside the function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm really looking for moving forward X bytes, not chars though. Could you explain what your search pattern does, possibly with references to documentation?

Comment: Done. It is also possible to automate the `[count]go` process though in a vim function (read current byte offset, add desired number, `go` there).

Comment: ... added automated function and command.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this starts to look good! There are two small differences between `[count]go` and your method: 1) `[count]go` adds an item to the jump list, so I can use `Ctrl+O` to quickly jump back to my previous position. 2) `[count]go` can be used without `:`, is it possible to introduce a new `[count]GO` that does your thing. Could you edit your answer to also match that behavior of `go`?

Comment: edited for both points

Comment: After changing `<c-c>` ti `GO`, your answer does exactly what I asked. Thanks! Small note: If I put your snippet in a single file ("vimrcnew"), and load it with `vim -u vimrcnew`, then the keybinding does not work (even though it works if I put it in my main `.vimrc`). Do you happen to know why that happens?

Comment: slightly edited answer - the cursor column was not the right one. Side effect: you have now only one jump back per line (should be ok for larger byte jumps). You probably need to use `set nocompatible` in your `vimrcnew` ?

Comment: ... last edit (hopefully) - when used with argument 0 (no count), it re-uses the latest byte offset jump value.

Comment: I've added an answer with my final solution. It's much shorter than your code and basically automates what I explained at the bottom of my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had a strong feeling i was missing something :)

Comment: I've changed the checkmark because your answer has a defect in byte counting (the answer on which you're basing the byte counting is incorrect). I've posted a [howto over there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3911/2720) and updated my answer here with the improved byte counting method. I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, and glad you found a general solution!