# How to get the current byte offset in whole file

Tags: vimscript, binary-file

I saw that you could display the current byte offset in the statusline using `%o`, but I found no function or command which does the same.  Is there a way of getting the current byte offset pragmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
function! FileOffset()
    return line2byte(line('.')) + col('.') - 1
endfunction
```

This returns the 1-based offset in file, which is the same as `%o` in `statusline`.  You can, of course, subtract 1 to get the 0-based offset.

Comment: One question, does `col('.')` actually return the byte offset in the line?  Last I looked, it just showed the cursor column.

Comment: @EvergreenTree According to `:help col()`: _[t]he result is a Number, which is the byte index of the column position given with {expr}_.  I take it that's the 1-based byte offset...

Comment: Will the answer work in a file having this line only: `abcäb` ? (I haven't checked)

Comment: @VanLaser It works in my quick tests.  You tell us if it still works after extended testing.

Comment: Just tested and it works :)

Answer (score 6):

The [other answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/how-to-get-the-current-byte-offset-in-whole-file/3850#3850) did not work for me when I opened a binary file without line ending. It seems that there is a bug in vim when it comes to counting bytes in a binary file without eol. (edit: yes, this was a bug. I have [submitted a patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/zX45zm-cnc0/-BWjjh5tlX8J), which got [accepted in 7.4.781](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/PnMWN0rujOk/hRxX91VZAc4J)).

To find the byte offset, while accounting for the bug in old Vim versions, use:

```
let offset = line2byte(line('.')) + col('.') - 1
if version < 781 && &l:binary == 1 && &l:eol == 0
    " Vim prior 7.4.781 had a bug where the line count is off by 1 or 2.
    " See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/zX45zm-cnc0/-BWjjh5tlX8J
    let offset += 1
    let offset += line('.') == 1
endif
```

This bug also affects the `%o` specifier in e.g. [`rulerformat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'rulerformat').